# Move the Menu Icon to the Right

Tags: mmenu

By default the Menu Icon to open the navigation menu is located on the LEFT side of the header - how do I move that to the RIGHT side?

I have search the support system and I was not able to find anything. I also looked into your tutorials and did not see it there either?

Comment: Are you developing a website or an Android app?

Comment: A website - if you go here http://www.ilgm.com with a mobile device you'll see it runniung.